# Extract specific word from the string using Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string `Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_Yakutat_CDP.png`

From the string above, I want to extract only the word after this word `Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_` and before `.png`.

So basically I want to extract after fourth word separated by underscore and till the word before .png

I am new to regex.

Finally I want only `Yakutat_CDP`.

Comment: You need to describe what exactly you want to do in the general case, not just on this particular string.

Comment: @interjay, ya i edited now

Comment: But you still didn't describe what you want to do in the general case. i.e. one which may contain a different string.

Comment: @interjay, i am trying to rename the files

Comment: Still not what I asked.... You need to write a general description like "I want to extract the fifth and sixth words, which are separated by underscores." (this is just an example, I don't know if it's what you actually need because you won't say). Otherwise you'll get an answer like the one below which only works with a specific string.

Comment: @interjay, ya thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is something like this:

```
import os

# I think you will have different jobs/pngs, so pass these variables from somewhere
jobPrefix = 'Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_'
pngString = 'Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_Yakutat_CDP.png'

# Split filename/extension
pngTitle = os.path.splitext(pngString)[0]

# Get the filename without the jobPrefix
finalTitle = pngTitle[len(jobPrefix):]
```

**Edit**

Try to avoid regular expressions as it is much slower in general than string slicing

Answer (score 2):

You can do it even without regex like so:

```
s = 'Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_Yakutat_CDP.png'
print(s[len('Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_'):-len('.png')])
```

In essence here I take the substring starting immediately after `Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_` and ending before `.png`.

Still probably a regex approach is more readable and maintanable:

```
import re
m = re.match('Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_(.*).png')
print(m[1])
```

Comment: I don't want to give explicitly the string name inside re.match(), Could you please help me regardless of any string (s) it should give output like after 'Job_Cluster_AK_Alaska_' and before '.png'

Comment: I am do not understand what is `the string name` in this context